Azure Functions, Angular and Cookies in local
I'm using Angular 18 and Azure Functions 4 isolated with .NET 8.
I added two entries to my hosts file:
127.0.0.1 apis.mytestapp.local
127.0.0.1 mytestapp.local
My Azure functions app is being assigned the port 7132 locally.
In my angular.json file I have my development serve configuration setup to use the host mytestapp.local listening on port 80.
When I start both my functions app and my angular app, I'm able to browse to the application on mytestapp.local.
The application makes calls to the api calling the apis.mytestapp.local:7132/api routes.
I have a function call that is supposed to set a cookie for auth and it is being done as follows:
var c = new HttpCookie("MY_Auth", tokenString)
{
    //CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();
    Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(1),
    Domain = ".mytestapp.local",
    //// Make the cookie available for the browser
    HttpOnly = true,
    SameSite = SameSite.Strict,
    Secure = false,
    Path = "/",
};

response.Cookies.Append(c);
await response.WriteStringAsync(proofKeyCodeExchangeResponse.RedirectUri).ConfigureAwait(false);

The response shown in the browser has the Set-Cookie header as I would expect, but in the Application tab of the dev tools, there are no cookies there.

I've tried a bunch of different approaches. I tried a .dev domain, as well as tweaking a bunch of the Cookie settings. I tried to put both the Azure functions app and the angular app on the same port.
No matter what I try though, I'm unable to get this working locally. I would really like to have local and a deployed environment work as similarly as possible to ensure I'm testing with the auth pieces in place.
How can I get an angular application with an azure function api backend running locally with an auth cookie being set and passed for all of the api calls?
